# is there any way to create new list from list based on missing number which would include last number from the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
below is the list:
lst = [0, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 13]
```

if lst start from 0 keep as is [0]. then next list would be [1,2,3], next would be [4,5] etc

```
final output should be:
[[0], [1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7], [8,9,10], [11, 12, 13]]
```

Tried below code to get missing number. But not sure how to create list groups using missing numbers.

```
missing = [x for x in range(lst[0], lst[-1]+1) if x not in lst]

print(missing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `result` with just the first element

```
result = [[lst[0]]]
#result = [ [0] ]
```

From the second element, create a list for every number. This list should range from the last number in the most recent `result` sublist to the current number in `lst`
i.e : From 1-3, 4-5, 6,7 etc

```
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    x = list(range(result[i-1][-1]+1, lst[i]+1))
    result.append(x)

print(result)
#[[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8], [9, 10], [11, 12, 13]]
```

Comment: what if we need to include 1st element too?